How can I use $config->useAccessFile('') in WebSVN config.php
I want browse svn repo in website with WebSVN.
This is my config
Apache httpd.conf
<Location "/websvn/">
    SetEnv WEBSVN_PATH_CONF "/var/www/html/websvn/include/config.php"
</Location>

WebSVN config.php
// ...other default code

$config->parentPath('/path/to/your/svn/repositories');

// ...other default code


And I can browse in 'localhost/websvn'
Now I wish to provide an authentication mechanism for WebSVN.
With docs, I add useAccessFile line to my config.php file:
// /var/svn/repositories/myrepo/conf/authz is my svn authz file
$config->useAccessFile('/var/svn/repositories/myrepo/conf/authz');

But is show error with No output on STDOUT.sh: svnauthz: command not found
enter image description here
How can I fix it
This is my software's ver
SVN 1.7.14
WebSVN 2.8.4
Php 7.4.33
Apache Http 2.4.6

I think maybe I don't have authz tool in SVN,so I have install subversion-tools,but it also doesn't work
